# Plotting a rarefaction curve using mean species richness in R

Tags: vegan

I have bird community matrices (presence-absence) for 10 sites (with 72 samples each) and would like to plot a single averaged sample-based rarefaction curve for all these sites. At the moment I've merely averaged individual estimates (for each site) generated by the specaccum function, but am unsure whether this is a sensible approach.

Comment: So you want to have a species accumulation curve over sampling units? Averaging random accumulations is OK, but with increasing number of random repetitions, the averages will converge to the estimates given directly by the "exact" method: why don't you want to use this method instead?

Comment: @JariOksanen Thank you for this. Yes, I want a species accumulation curve over sampling units. Figuring out which method is better suited for averaging across sites is  want I'm trying to do. So, I'll go with the "exact" method. Just to be clear about my approach: I'm dividing sums of richness, sd, and freq from individual sites by the total number of sites (10).

Comment: @littleraspberry In R. It's indicated in the title.